# Ajax - security breach? - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I build a system in php, i have page name x.php
and in this page i create variable name $accountid and get the acocunt id from the sesstion.

now i have others varibles in php at the same page that calls to functions that in other page called functions.php, and deliver the accountid, the function return info about the account (for example the name of the user..)

is this security breach?

i mean the user can call in ajax to the function with other accountid and then he can get info about other account?

here is the code example:

```
<?php 
    include "Includs/Config.php";

    if(!isset($_SESSION[get("session_name")])) { 
            header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $accountid = getAccountid($_SESSION[get("session_name")]);
    $e = getECategorys($accountid);
?>


function getE($accountId){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE `accountid` = $accountId");   

    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        // get the info about the account..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. User can get information by passing another accountId to that function. 
Solution: All you can do is check session variable and passed accountId. You can put condition, If session variable (accountId) is matched with passed accountId to that function then only retrieve data otherwise gives an error.

Second solution is to achieve this thing with class base, setting private member variable of accountId.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, it seems you are getting `accountId` from the `$_SESSION` so this seems to be safe.

Also, users can't call php functions directly using ajax.

Actually, you shouldn't consider AJAX as something else than a simple HTTP request.